# Spring boot auth2 dependencies >> differences between spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

What is the difference between the following 2 dependencies and when to use which?

```
  #maven pom.xml format deps:

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

From what I researched you should use:

**resource-server:** When a client app is already verified via the authorization server. The client then sends the token in an authorization header to our spring boot server. The token then gets verified on the server and access is granted to server resources.

**client**: The spring boot app is the client now and will make a request to an authorization server from which it gets a token. This token can now be used in additional request to other resource servers to obtain certain resources.

Is my understanding correct. Am I missing any details?

Comment: resource server, your application can accept tokens. While client, your server is a client calling someone else to get a token and then consume other services. So yeah you got it right

Comment: @Toerktumlare So if I want to implement google login on the frontend to access certain resources on the backend I do the following:

pass the token from the frontend to my resource server >> 
Verify the token on the resource server >> give back resource right?

Comment: i dont understand when you say google "login on the frontend" google login is implemented in the backend https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.1.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2login#google-login

Comment: This is a good ol' fashioned "read the docs" question. Always check out the [spring.io project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#learn) for links to the latest docs. See Client and Resource Server sections on the [OAuth2 page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's understand everything through a diagram:

[image]

> **OAuth2 defines few roles:**

**Client:** The client (REST API client) is the system that access the protected resources from ***Resource server***. To access resources from the ***Resource server***, the Client must hold the appropriate Access Token.

Client uses this maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Resource Server:** This Server is an application that protects resources via OAuth tokens. The job of the ***Resource server*** is to validate the token before serving a resource to the client.

Resource server uses this maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Authorization Server:** This Server receives requests from the Client for Access Tokens and issues them upon successful authentication. The service acting as a middleman between client and resource owner.

Authorization server uses this maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```